# Problem with AMD HD Radeon 8570M Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, lenovo

I Have a Lenovo Essential G505s.
I Have tried various linux distros but my graphics card seems to have very less support for linux distros.

I have an AMD HD Radeon 8650G (int) / AMD HD Radeon 8570M (discrete) Graphics.
All other devices work Perfect but the graphics card.
I Installed Ubuntu 13.04/13.10 and then 14.04, but none worked with "swithcable graphics" activated.
Although 14.04 worked with `UMA Graphics` mode (integrated Rad. HD 8650G) but had no support for 8570M. I observed colour depth problems (banding of gradients everywhere).

I installed AMD proprietary drivers and it seemed to work averagely well for integrated graphics but there were still problems with discrete Graphics(8570M).

I want to know will I ever get support for my graphics card, or how can I help in the development of driver for my graphics card.

Comment: You can report all bugs in the open source radeon drivers to the radeon project - they have an IRC channel, mailing list and bug tracker, you will find the details at http://www.x.org/wiki/radeon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the graphics card driver:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

Then reboot.